# Stop scrolling behavior iphone, on searchbar in fixed header (already on top, so scroll is not needed)

Tags: ios, iphone, search, input, scroll

I have a fixed header with a search bar incorporated in it. The search bar appears when clicking a magnifying glass. The search bar is always positioned at the top of the screen. Now when scrolling down the screen on iPhone the header, being fixed, stays visible at the top of the screen. However, when toggling the search bar when scrolled away from the top a scrolling up is happening. How could I prevent this behavior? Tried a number of solutions also found here, but none work.

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: Hi, it is like this site: www.gitman.com. So on iphone and also iPad. But on iPad it is even "worse" because it just scrolls directly to the top of the page, when focus is on the input field.